# Model with custom table name return values of other type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Say we have a model, and it connected to table with different name:

`UserConnector.table_name = 'users'`

When we try to get values from this model, we got some strange:

```
> UserConnector.first
  UserConnector Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> User id: 1, login: "admin", mail: "admin@example.net"
```

Type of returned value is `User`, not `UserConnector`.

How shall I force activerecord to return values of appropriate type?

Comment: Do you have a `User` model?

Comment: I have, but UserConnector.first.attributes returns appropriate attributes.

Comment: Strange.  Can't you just use `user_connectors` as the table name to avoid confusion?

Comment: No I can't. It is external database.

Comment: How about renaming `User` class?  Same deal, external table?

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
self.abstract_class = true
```

in the beginning of the class, could it work?